# Idiomatic way to struct.unpack from BytesIO?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some byte data that wants to be parsed as a stream, since bytes earlier in the sequence control the interpretation of downstream bytes. So BytesIO looks like the thing I want. But I also want to use the facilities provided by the struct module. But struct's interfaces aren't streaming. Is there a clever/idiomatic way to marry the two?

By way of example, here's an example chunk of data:

```
b'\n\x00\x02\x90\x10\x00\n\x00\x02`\x10\x00\n\x00\x02\x80\x10\x00'
```

I want to pull the first 4 bytes as an unsigned big endian int (e.g. `struct.unpack(fmt='>I'`). Because the next byte is 0x10, I know there should be one more byte, which turns out to be 0x00. And then it starts over again, read the next 4 (0x0A000290), wash, rinse, repeat. The byte(s) immediately following each 4 byte id, trigger a variety of downstream reads (some bytes, some shorts).

I could do things like

```
stream = b'\n\x00\x02\x90\x10\x00\n\x00\x02`\x10\x00\n\x00\x02\x80\x10\x00'
while stream:
    id = struct.unpack('>I', stream[:4])
    stream = stream[4:]
    ...
```

But that seems less than elegant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I generally do is:

```
def unpack(stream, fmt):
    size = struct.calcsize(fmt)
    buf = stream.read(size)
    return struct.unpack(fmt, buf)
```

For example:

```
>>> b = io.BytesIO(b'\n\x00\x02\x90\x10\x00\n\x00\x02`\x10\x00\n\x00\x02\x80\x10\x00')
>>> print(unpack(b, '>I'))
(167772816,)
>>> print(unpack(b, '>I'))
(268438016,)
>>> print(unpack(b, '>I'))
(39849984,)
>>> print(unpack(b, '>I'))
(167772800,)
>>> print(unpack(b, '>H'))
(4096,)
```

If you want to know if you're consumed the whole stream, you can always just do this:

```
buf = stream.read(1)
if buf:
    raise ValueError("Stream not consumed")
```

But it's probably simpler to just call the same function you're already using:

```
>>> def ensure_finished(stream):
...     try:
...         unpack(stream, 'c')
...     except struct.error:
...         pass
...     else:
...         raise ValueError('Stream not consumed')
>>> ensure_finished(b)
```

If you're using a stream that may `read` less than the requested number of bytes, you'll want to use a `while` loop to keep reading and appending until EOF or you get enough bytes. Otherwise, this is all you need.

Comment: OK, this is probably the answer I'll go with. Is there an easy (builtin) way to test when I'm at the end of the stream? If not, I guess I can make a helper for that too (test the current position against len() of underlying sequence).

Comment: @TravisGriggs: You're at the end of the stream when a `read()` returns 0 bytes.

Comment: Bummer. That would imply that I can't test before calling unpack() if I'm done or not, but rather have to call unpack(), trap the 0 case read, and either raise an exception or return None, and then on the calling side handle that. I had hoped to be able to do something like `while not io.atEnd(): unpack(), unpack(), unpack()...`

Comment: Would it be awful to implement `atEnd(stream): return stream.tell() == len(stream.getbuffer())` ?

Comment: @TravisGriggs: This is a general issue with Python file-like objects: They're intended to be used in EAFP style, where you loop forever until you hit EOF, instead of looping until an EOF test. But if you really want the test, you can do it the same way as anything else. For just `BytesIO`, your way is fine. More generically, do `stream.seek(0, io.SEEK_END); streamlen = stream.tell(); stream.seek(0)` at the start, then just compare `while stream.tell() < streamlen:`.

Comment: @TravisGriggs: You can check for EOF in the `unpack()` function by checking `len(buf) != size` after the `buf = stream.read(size)`.

Comment: @martineau: But that doesn't really help. What are you going to do there, besides raise an exception? It's too late to affect the `while` loop's condition. And if you raise an exception, that will look exactly the same (except for the text of exc.message) as if you just called `unpack`, so… why bother?

Comment: @abarnert: OK, then simply use a `cond = True`, `while cond:`, then set `cond = False` if a `struct.error` exception occurs during an `unpack()` call.

Comment: @martineau: Why use a `while cond:` instead of just `while True:` and then exit the loop (with a `break`, `return`, or exception)? It just adds extra verbosity (and more code to maintain and debug) for no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `struct`s buffer API:

```
buf = b'\n\x00\x02…'
offset = 0
id = struct.unpack_from('>I', buf, offset); offset += 4
⋮
x = struct.unpack_from('…', buf, offset)
```

If you want to avoid stating the offset after each operation, you can write a little wrapper, like so:

```
class unpacker(object):
    def __init__(self, buf):
        self._buf = buf
        self._offset = 0
    def __call__(self, fmt):
        result = struct.unpack_from(fmt, self._buf, self._offset)
        self._offset += struct.calcsize(fmt)
        return result

⋮

unpack = unpacker(buf)
id = unpack('>I')
⋮
x = unpack('…')
```

Comment: This is actually even less elegant than using slicing; if you later add a new int between positions 4 and 8, you have to update all of the following offsets.

Comment: Also, from your edit, there's no such type as `buffer`. And I'm not sure what type you're looking for; `bytes` already supports the buffer API just fine.

Comment: @abarnert: Sorry, I assumed Python 2.x.

Comment: `[struct.unpack_from('>I',buffer,i) for i in range(0,len(buffer),4)]`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: The whole point of what the OP wants is to do "a variety of downstream reads (some bytes, some shorts)", where the type of the later reads depends on the earlier ones, so that isn't going to help.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Python 2.x's `bytes` (aka `str`) also supports the buffer API just fine, so that still doesn't add anything. (Also, in 2.x, why are you using the `b` prefix anyway?)

Comment: The updated version is now no worse than the OP's original code, but it's not really any better, either. You still have to manually match up the offset to the format, which is easy to get wrong and hard to debug.

Comment: @abarnert: I didn't know that about 2.x; thanks. I've adjust the answer to accommodate changing requirements over time. The reason I suggested this approach is to avoid copying bytes (which I assumed is why unpackFrom exists in the first place). Does Python 3.x (maybe even 2.x?) create slices in O(1) time and space? If so, I'll just delete my answer.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: No, it doesn't create slices in O(1) time. But the OP isn't worried about performance, he's worried about "elegance", which presumably means that it's repeating the same information in two different forms that bothers him.

Comment: @abarnert: The OP didn't  say they aren't worried about performance (Indeed, since it's the slicing that they consider "less than elegant", it's not too much of a stretch to infer that, by "elegant", they might have meant, "efficient"). Besides, since the O(n) time and space of slices potentially renders their code O(n²), even a few megabytes of input might make them start to worry.

Comment: It is always a stretch to assume that "elegant" means "efficient". And the fact that the OP explicitly asked for a "clever or idiomatic way to merge" a `BytesIO`-like stream and `struct` to avoid having the specify the length and the format separately and in parallel implies pretty strongly what he meant by "elegance" in this case.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about BytesIO (a streaming file-like object).  The accepted answer is correct, and points toward `.read()`.